# Can you somehow use a local function on a global level in python?

Tags: python, function, espeak, local-functions, global-functions

I'm writing a program and I'm using `espeak` library to make it speak. The thing is I've already written my program but now I want to make a way to ask the user in the beginning if he wants the program to talk to him or just rely on reading. So if he said yes the program speaks using `espeak`, but if he said no the program does not use `espeak`, so I'm stuck at the no part.

I want to ask a question and use the right function based on the answer, but the problem is that its a local function so when you use the function `espeak()` it says

```
NameError: name 'espeak' is not defined
```

Here's how what I want it:

```
import os
ai_talk = False
# MAKE THE AI SPEAK, OR NOT
def speak_or_not():
    global ai_talk
    
    speak_or_n = input("Do you want me to speak or not?\nPS: input Y/N\n").casefold()
    while not ai_talk:
        if (speak_or_n == "y") or (speak_or_n == "yes"):
            def espeak(text):
                command = 'espeak -v +f2 -p25 '+'"'+text+'"'
                os.system(command)
                return
            ai_talk = True

        elif (speak_or_n == "n") or (speak_or_n == "no"):
            def espeak(text):
                return
            ai_talk = True

        else:
            speak_or_n = input("You can only input Y/N").casefold()
    return

speak_or_not()

print("Hello there! how are you doing?")
espeak("Hello there! how are you doing?")
```

So is there a way to make that `def espeak()` function work on a global level so I can use it for the rest of my program?

(other than coping the hole thing and pasting it in the no section without the `espeak` function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to write it such that `speak_or_not` returns the `espeak` function.  I've added type annotations to make it easier to see how the inner function interacts with the outer function -- the `speak_or_not` function returns a `Callable[[str], None]` (a function that takes a `str` argument and returns `None`), and both version of `espeak` match this type.

```
import os
from typing import Callable

def speak_or_not() -> Callable[[str], None]:
    """Return a function that either makes the AI speak or is a no-op."""
    speak_or_n = input("Do you want me to speak or not?\nPS: input Y/N\n").casefold()
    while True:
        if speak_or_n in ("y", "yes"):
            def espeak(text: str) -> None:
                os.system(f'espeak -v +f2 -p25 "{text}"')
            return espeak
        if speak_or_n in ("n", "no"):
            def espeak(text: str) -> None:
                return
            return espeak
        speak_or_n = input("You can only input Y/N").casefold()

espeak = speak_or_not()

print("Hello there! how are you doing?")
espeak("Hello there! how are you doing?")
```

Note that the `global ai_talk` is not necessary because this value was never used outside of the function, and in fact within the function it's only ever used to break the loop, which is unnecessary if you `return` once the terminating condition is met, so even within the function the value is not needed at all.

Comment: nitpick: `in` check is faster for tuples up to ~30 elements. So, by using `.. in `('yes', 'y')` instead of a set you can save couple nanoseconds of machine time

Answer (score 0):

If you simply `return espeak`, you can save the definition you want in the main program.  This is how Python decorators work.  Here is trivial example:

```
def fpick(flag):
    if flag:
        def display():
            print('flag was set')
    else:
        def display():
            print('flag was off')

    return display

display = fpick(True)
display()

display = fpick(False)
display()
```

Output:

```
flag was set
flag was off

 was set
flag
```

was off